# How to group IP list by subnet in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, ip, subnet

I need to group IP list by subnet (first 3 octets) to count it. For example, if I have Ips

```
123.12.12.12
123.12.12.11
123.12.11.11
```

I have to get such result:

```
123.12.12 | 2
123.12.11 | 1
```

I googled this expample:

```
select 
substr(ip,1,locate('.',ip,locate('.',ip)+1)-1) 
as ip, count(ip) as count
from ip_list
group by ip ORDER BY count  DESC
```

But it groups the list only by first two octets. I was lost in all these `locate(locate(locate(...)))`. Can somebody help to modify this to get proper results?

Comment: 123.0.0.0 is class A, so (default) subnet mask is 255.0.0.0, not 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should have used `group by` *expression name*.

```
select 
--   locate( '.', ip, locate( '.', ip, locate( '.', ip ) + 1 ) + 1 ) as l,
   substr( ip, 1, locate( '.', ip
                          , locate( '.', ip
                                    , locate( '.', ip ) + 1 ) + 1 ) - 1 ) as subip,
   count(ip) as count
from ip_list
group by ( subip )
order by count desc
;
```

**EDIT 1**:
Use of `locate` is not required. `SUBSTR_INDEX` can be used to filter the subset of IP's.

**Example**:

```
select
       substring_index( ip, '.', 3 ) as subip
     , count(ip) as count
  from ip_list
 group by ( subip )
 order by count desc
```

**Refer to Documentation**:

- [**MySQL:  SUBSTR(str,pos,len)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

  - Return a substring len characters long from string str, starting at
    position pos.
- [**MySQL: SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

  - Returns the substring from string str before count occurrences of the
    delimiter delim.

Comment: Just to add that `substring_index(ip, '.', 3)` would be a more elegant way of cutting the last part of the IP, instead of using substr() and locate().

Comment: @Botch: That is true. Answer was just given to fix the issue. An alternative solution is added now.

Answer (score 1):

Using this logic I'm afraid you'll be needing another layer of `locate` there:

```
substr(ip, 1, locate('.', ip, locate('.', ip, locate('.', ip)+1) +1) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
GROUP BY INET_ATON(ip)/256
```

Comment: only if you are already storing IPs converted with INET_ATON()

Answer (score 0):

If you make an IP binary, you can apply a mask over it which only keeps the first 3 parts of your IP address. The mask looks like this:

```
11111111111111111111111100000000
```

So, as a digit, it looks like:

```
SELECT CONV('11111111111111111111111100000000' ,2,10) as mask;
-- Result: 4294967040
```

If you do a bitwise AND over your IP address with this mask, you will get a result like this:

```
SELECT
'1.0.207.199',                
INET_NTOA( INET_ATON( '1.0.207.199') & 4294967040 ) ;
-- Result:
-- 1.0.207.199
-- 1.0.207.0
```

INET_ATON converts an ip (A)ddress (TO) a (N)umber, and INET_NTOA visa versa (although the real meaning stands for ASCII TO Network, but I like this shofthand better ;-).

So, you can group by your IP addresses like this:

```
SELECT
    INET_NTOA( INET_ATON( ip ) & 4294967040 ) AS ipgroup, 
    COUNT(ip) AS count
FROM ip_list
GROUP BY ipgroup 
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
select INET_NTOA((INET_ATON(IP)>>X)<<X)
from TABLE
group by
```

X should be 32-subnet

i.e:

```
select INET_NTOA((INET_ATON('1.1.2.15')>>8)<<8)
```